# php mysql select result without field names

Tags: php, mysql

Is there any way to get only values from a select using pdo?

```
select city from customer
```

I want as result an array with only cities values no index 'city', eg.:

```
['milano','rome']
```

thx.

Comment: what you have tried so far ?

Comment: no way at the moment object or array always returns field name as 'index' or property...
I know that but I don't want browse array to get all values
I need them to set a json array it is a query over 100k records
overload matter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [`fetchAll` manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php#refsect1-pdostatement.fetchall-examples):

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("select city from customer");
$sth->execute();

$result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);
var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
$cities = array();
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT city FROM cities");

while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $cities[] = $row['city'];
}
```

Comment: you need to define `$cities` array